# Differences of size in du -hs and du -b

Tags: linux, unix

When I look at `du -hs` for a directory, I get around 956k, but when I do `du -b` for the same directory I get around 604347 which would be around 590k. Why do I have such a large difference (600k vs 956k) between these two commands. Am I reading it incorrectly ?

Comment: Better suited for https://unix.stackexchange.com/ than SO.

Comment: Please update your post with: 1) `du -sk`, 2) `du-sb`, 3) `du -hs`

Comment: @FoggyDay why should he?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `-b` does two things, first it reports the *apparent size* instead of disk usage; second it reports with the granularity of a single byte.

The main reason for a file to take up more space than its apparent size, or even actual size, is that the filesystem works with fixed-size blocks. So even a file of only 1 byte will take up a whole block.

What you see is the effect of many small files.

In the ext4 filesystem, the default block size is 4096 bytes. In your scenario, a smaller block size would probably be beneficial. On the other hand, if your disk is supposed to store mostly large files, it makes sense to increase the block size. The organization of blocks, after all, also takes up space on the disk. So the value 4096 is a compromise in this regard, but also fits to modern hard drives, which internally work with 4096 byte sectors.

Answer (score 0):

If you `man du` you going to see that `-b` is equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1` and this means:

> print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent
>   size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in ('sparse')
>   files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like.

So the `-b` option might show small values that might be smaller than the disk usage size of the referred file/directory although not always true as explained by the manual.