# Show average file output speed once for loop is complete, for benchmarking purposes?

Tags: bash

Sorry for being unclear my follow mates,

So to elaborate and possibly answer my own question, while Distro1Analysis.txt is being written to, calculate output speed in kb/s and when output is done  then average output speed and print to screen.

The second part, its own question really, is quite simple, I'm not a computer scientist or advanced programmer, but I am certain there's an relatively easy way to improve the overall execution speed of the script which asking what is the speed culprit, how the script was written, the chosen programs, the mix of programs (i.e., is it faster to use 3 instances of the same program as opposed to one instance of 3 different programs...)  For instance, could recursive-ness be used and how?

I was orignally going to ask how to benchmark the speed of a program to run one command, but it seemed simpler to use an overarching (global) benchmark hence the question.  But any help you can provide would be useful.

**Rdepends Version**

```
ps -A &>> Distro1Analysis.txt && sudo service --status-all &>> Distro1Analysis.txt && \
for z in $(dpkg -l | awk '/^[hi]i/{print $2}' | grep -v '^lib'); do \
printf "\n$z:" && \
aptitude show $z | grep -E 'Uncompressed Size' && \
result=$(apt-rdepends 2>/dev/null $z | grep -v "Depends")
final=$(apt show 2>/dev/null $result | grep -E "Package|Installed-Size" | sed "/APT/d;s/Installed-Size: //");
if [[ (${#final} -le 700) ]]; then echo $final; else :; fi done &>> Distro1Analysis.txt
```

**Depends Version**

```
ps -A &>> Distro1Analysis.txt && sudo service --status-all &>> Distro1Analysis.txt && \
for z in $(dpkg -l | awk '/^[hi]i/{print $2}' | grep -v '^lib'); do \
printf "\n$z:" && \
aptitude show $z | grep -E 'Uncompressed Size' && \
printf "\n" && \
apt show 2>/dev/null $(aptitude search '!~i?reverse-depends("^'$z'$")' -F "%p" | \
sed 's/:i386$//') | grep -E 'Package|Installed-Size' | sed '/APT/d;s/^.*Package:/\t&/;N;s/\n/ /'; done &>> Distro1Analysis.txt
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue. "Output speed" means the speed at which `Distro1Analysis.txt` is written?

Comment: Your question is quite vague, but might I suggest the `time` command in bash.

Comment: Yes, apparently I am frequently more vague then I believe.  Dozens of users just can't be wrong.  I will elaborate in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

> calculate output speed in kb/s and when output is done then average
>   output speed and print to screen

Here's an answer that's basically

1. Starting your script to run in the background.
2. Checking the size of its output file every two seconds with `du -b`.

Run the following bash script like so: `$ bash scriptoutmon.sh subscript.sh Distro1Analysis.txt 12 10 2`

```
scriptoutmon.sh usage:
$1 : Path to the subscript to run
$2 : Path to output file to monitor
$3 : How long to run scriptoutmon.sh script in seconds.
$4 : How long to run the subscript ($1)
$5 : Tick length for displayed updates in seconds.
```

`scriptoutmon.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Date: 2020-04-13T23:03Z
# Author: Steven Baltakatei Sandoval
# License: GPLv3+ https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html
# Description: Runs subscript and measures change in file size of a specified file.
# Usage: scriptoutmon.sh [ path to subscript ] [ path to subscript output file ] [ script TTL (s) ] [ subscript TTL (s) ] [ tick size (s) ]
# References:
#  [1]: Adrian Pronk (2013-02-22). "Floating point results in Bash integer division". https://stackoverflow.com/a/15015920 
#  [2]: chronitis (2012-11-15). "bc: set number of digits after decimal point". https://askubuntu.com/a/217575
#  [3]: ypnos (2020-02-12). "Differences of size in du -hs and du -b". https://stackoverflow.com/a/60196741

# == Function Definitions ==
echoerr() { echo "$@" 1>&2; } # display message via stderr
getSize() { echo $(du -b "$1" | awk '{print $1}'); } # output file size in bytes. See [3].

# == Initialize settings ==
SUBSCRIPT_PATH="$1" # path to subscript to run
SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_PATH="$2" # path to output file generated by subscript
SCRIPT_TTL="$3" # set script time-to-live in seconds
SUBSCRIPT_TTL="$4" # set subscript time-to-live in seconds
TICK_SIZE="$5" # update tick size (in seconds)

# == Perform work ==
timeout $SUBSCRIPT_TTL bash "$SUBSCRIPT_PATH" & # run subscript for SCRIPT_TTL seconds.
# note: SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_PATH should be path of output file generated by subscript.sh .
if [ -f $SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_PATH ]; then SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_INITIAL_SIZE=$(getSize "$SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_PATH"); else SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_INITIAL_SIZE="0"; fi # save initial size if file exists.

echoerr "Running $(basename "$SUBSCRIPT_PATH") and then monitoring rate of file size changes to $(basename "$SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_PATH")." # explain displayed output

# Calc and display subscript output file size changes
while [ $SECONDS -lt $SCRIPT_TTL ]; do # loop while script age (in seconds) less than SCRIPT_TTL.
    if [ $SECONDS -ge $TICK_SIZE ]; then # if after first tick
    OUTPUT_PREVIOUS_SIZE="$OUTPUT_CURRENT_SIZE" ; # save size previous tick
    OUTPUT_CURRENT_SIZE=$(getSize "$SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_PATH") ; # save size current tick
    BYTES_WRITTEN=$(( $OUTPUT_CURRENT_SIZE - $OUTPUT_PREVIOUS_SIZE )) ; # calc size difference between current and previous ticks.
    WRITE_SPEED_BYTES_PER_SECOND=$(($BYTES_WRITTEN / $TICK_SIZE)) ; # calc write speed in bytes per second
    WRITE_SPEED_KILOBYTES_PER_SECOND=$( echo "scale=3; $WRITE_SPEED_BYTES_PER_SECOND / 1000" | bc -l ) ; # calc write speed in kilobytes per second. See [1], [2].
    echo "File size change rate (KB/sec):"$WRITE_SPEED_KILOBYTES_PER_SECOND ;
    else # if first tick
    OUTPUT_CURRENT_SIZE=$(getSize "$SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_PATH") # save size current tick (initial)
    fi

    sleep "$TICK_SIZE"; # wait a tick
done

SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_FINAL_SIZE=$(getSize "$SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_PATH") # save final size

# == Display results ==
SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_TOTAL_CHANGE_BYTES=$(( $SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_FINAL_SIZE - $SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_INITIAL_SIZE )) # calc total size change in bytes
SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_TOTAL_CHANGE_KILOBYTES=$( echo "scale=3; $SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_TOTAL_CHANGE_BYTES / 1000" | bc -l ) # calc total size change in kilobytes. See [1], [2].
echoerr "$SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_TOTAL_CHANGE_KILOBYTES kilobytes added to $SUBSCRIPT_OUTPUT_PATH size in $SUBSCRIPT_TTL seconds."

exit 0;
```

You should get output like this:

```
baltakatei@debianwork:/tmp$ bash scriptoutmon.sh subscript.sh Distro1Analysis.txt 12 10 2
Running subscript.sh and then monitoring rate of file size changes to Distro1Analysis.txt.
File size change rate (KB/sec):6.302
File size change rate (KB/sec):.351
File size change rate (KB/sec):.376
File size change rate (KB/sec):.345
File size change rate (KB/sec):.335
15.419 kilobytes added to Distro1Analysis.txt size in 10 seconds.
baltakatei@debianwork:/tmp$
```

Increase $3 and $4 to monitor the script longer (perhaps to let it finish its work).

> The second part, its own question really

I'd suggest making it a separate question.